# How to use a Twitter stream source in Hazelcast Jet without needing a DAG?

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I want to do simple analysis on a live stream of tweets.

How do you use a Twitter stream source in Hazelcast Jet without needing a DAG?

**Details**

The encapsulation of Twitter API is pretty good at [StreamTwitterP.java](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-demos/blob/master/cryptocurrency-sentiment-analysis/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/demo/core/StreamTwitterP.java).

However, the caller uses that as part of a DAG, c/o:

```
Vertex twitterSource = 
  dag.newVertex("twitter", StreamTwitterP.streamTwitterP(properties, terms));
```

My use case doesn't need the power of DAG, so I'd rather avoid that needless extra complexity.

To avoid a DAG, I'm looking to use SourceBuilder to define a new data source for live stream of tweets.

I assume that would have code similar to StreamTwitterP.java, mentioned above, however it's not clear to me the fit using the API of Hazelcast JET.

I was referring to [SourceBuilder example from the docs](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/latest/manual/#build-a-stream-source-with-event-timestamps).

Comment: In the same repository, you can find a sample that uses the `SourceBuilder`: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-demos/blob/master/cryptocurrency-sentiment-analysis/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/demo/CryptocurrencySentimentAnalysis.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a processor to a pipeline source:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
p.drawFrom(Sources.<String>streamFromProcessor("twitter", 
    streamTwitterP(properties, terms)))
...
```

There's also twitterSource version that uses `SourceBuilder` [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-demos/blob/898be186cdbff75a19d447cd64eaa3f2b4393d09/cryptocurrency-sentiment-analysis/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/demo/CryptocurrencySentimentAnalysis.java#L178-L181).